# What is the definition of Bluetooth peripheral device?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

What is the basic definition of a bluetooth peripheral device, bluetooth master device and a bluetooth slave device, and what are the functions of each of them?
How to define them in a BLE system? Currently I have a BLE development kit. If I want to connect my system in such a way, such that, I have a controller, an Android device, and 3 lights, that I want to connect with the controller. I should be able to control the lights from the mobile, such that, when I send a signal from the Android, it should go to the controller, and then, the controller should accordingly to the lights.

Comment: @LucasRamage - tags are for what a question is *about* not what it trivially mentions in passing.  This question was really far too broad to belong here, you'll note the tag you wanted to add is entirely absent from the content of the answer that was accepted; if the asker hadn't been willing to settle for that it would have needed to be closed, and probably still should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Master (or "central") devices**
Scan for other devices. Usually, the master is the smartphone/tablet/PC.

**Slave (or "peripheral") devices**
Advertise and wait for connections. Usually, the slave is the BLE module.

**Client devices**
Access remote resources over a BLE link using the GATT protocol. Usually, the master is also the client.

**Server devices**
Have a local database and access control methods, and provide resources to the remote client. Usually, the slave is also the server.